# Open (lx)terminal on startup, run program in it

Tags: pi-4, raspbian-buster, c++, bash, systemd

I have the following service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Create test directory
After=graphical.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
User=pi
ExecStart=/home/pi/Desktop/startup-script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

This service is calling a script "startup-script.sh", located on the /Desktop.

My startup-script is looking like:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo mkdir /home/pi/Desktop/test

sudo lxterminal -e /home/pi/Desktop/exe
```

Now the script is creating a new directory `test` at startup via the service, but it is not opening a new terminal and running my C++ program `exe` in it.

Now, when I just run my startup-script like `sudo ./startup-script.sh`, it is both creating a new directory `test` and opening a new lxterminal and running my C++ `exe` program in it, but the terminal is not opening on startup and I want this to happen.

Is it possible to do anything like this in the startup service: (this is not working.)

```
sudo lxterminal -e ./home/pi/Desktop/startup-script.sh &
```

Any thoughts on a solution to this?

**Update** with info from comments:
The program `home/pi/Desktop/exe` must be run when the RPi is running, so all the time, but lxterminal does not have to been run on startup anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running a systemd service, there is only a very limited environment available to always have a defined starting point. In particular, you do not have a `path` variable set, so `lxterminal` and other programs will not be found. You have to use the full path for all called programs.

And please don't use `sudo` in your script. Instead omit line `User=pi` in the Unit file. Services are executed with root rights by default. There is no need to wrap the two commands into a bash script. It's only an additional level of execution. And as you updated, there is no need to run the program "exe" in a lxterminal, so you should use this Unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=My exe program
After=graphical.target

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /home/pi/Desktop/test
ExecStart=/home/pi/Desktop/exe

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Now you can manage your service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable myexe.service
rpi ~$ systemctl status myexe.service
rpi ~$ systemctl start|stop|restart myexe.service
```

and all other commands from systemctl.

Comment: Forget the delay. That was a mistake. The script is just making a folder and starting lxterminal with my exe program in it.

Comment: @jrn6270 How long is exe running?

Comment: I must be run when the RPi is running, so all the time. I can't get it to work with your answer, but lxterminal does not have to been run on startup anyway... I made a little workaround. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @jrn6270 OK, that's a real service always running in the background. I will modify my answer.

Comment: @jrn6270 If my answer helped you, it would be nice, if you could accept it? :-)

Comment: Thank you. I can always count on you for an answer. Hope you are doing well in these corona-times :-)

Comment: @jrn6270 I have much of time to answer :) My gouvernment restricted me to stay home ...